# how can I move the edges relative to their common center?

Tags: modeling

I want to slightly corrent the shape of the arch by pushing these faces proportionaly in different directions:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You could try with Scale (S) on x, y or Z or two at the same time, like X and Z but not Y (Press S, Shift Y// to exclude the Y)

Comment: this not working

Comment: You should include your tool bars in the screen shot so we can see what your settings are. You could try moving the 3D cursor to the "common center" and then scale relative to the 3d cursor. Assuming the object is symmetrical you could also try turning on Mirror X and then just moving one of the points.

Comment: @DredWolf what the first commentor suggested is correct, but you need to make sure you've centred the 3d cursor between your two edges with shift+s, and selecting cursor to selection, then tell blender to scale on the 3d cursor

Comment: Assuming you want your arch to be symmetrical, I would add an edge down the middle. cut it in half, give it a _Mirror_  modifier, and work on one half, possibly with proportional editing.

Comment: Thanks! I add 3D Cursor berween edges, turn on scaling with 3D Cursor and scaled by Y axis